# Javascript redirect from MVC action result keeps appending domain

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I am not an expert in javascript and have been struggling with the following for a while.  I hope someone can guide me.

I have an action link on my MVC website like this

```
<a href="@Url.Action("MyAction", "Home", new { name = "Test" })" class="myClick">
    <img alt="" src="@ViewBag.ImageUrl">
</a>
```

In my site.js file I have the following

```
$(".myClick").on("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        type: this.method,
        success: function (result) {
            window.open(result.Url, '_blank');
        }
    });
});
```

My controller action returns a JsonResult object allowing get and I do get the URL returned to my javascript function.  The problem is the windoe.open keeps on opening with [myDomain]/[returnedUrl]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If the result URL isn't a *complete* URL (`http://some.domain/whatever`) then the browser understands that to mean that you want to use the current domain.

Comment: Your not cancelling the default redirect. Add `return false;` after the `$.ajax(){ ... });` lines of code

Comment: I'd probably use `e.preventDefault()` as well. But you'll have to add the `e` parameter to your event handler function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your url is an absolute url (`http://www.my.site.com`). Otherwise, your browser will interpret your url to be on the current domain automatically.